# What kind of applications need credit card verification on Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku

I am trying to follow the Java tutorial on 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java .
However, when I deploy the application to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
remote: -----> Launching... 
remote:  !     Push rejected, Please verify your account in order to change resources (please enter a credit card) For more information, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing Verify now at https://heroku.com/verify 
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to stormy-stream-7644.
```

Do I need credit card verification to deploy this simple application?

It is stated on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification#no-credit-or-debit-card that it should work without a credit/debit card, but still I am asked to do the verification.

Comment: What exactly is the question? They're just asking you to verify your account.

Comment: It turns out that there was a bug on Heroku's side. See https://status.heroku.com/incidents/815 . It would be nice if the 'duplicate' question would be removed, because it is not a duplicate at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any non-Heroku addon will require a credit card. That means the [Heroku PostgreSQL](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql) database and [Heroku Redis](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-redis) do not. But addons like [Papertrail](https://addons.heroku.com/papertrail) will require a CC.

**EDIT**

It looks like there is currently a bug that is causing this. Your probably getting that error and should not be. Please open a ticket at http://help.heroku.com

Comment: It was a bug at Heroku's side indeed, it is resolved now. See https://status.heroku.com/incidents/815

Comment: This bug seems to affect many of the getting started tutorials all of which use the papertrail add on.

Comment: The bug was resolved and should not be a problem anymore. The tutorials use Papertrail to demonstrate how addons work, at which point you need to verify your account. But you should be able to deploy and get an app working before that.

Comment: Seems we can't add heroku redis also without verifying.